# Getting odd package-related error when trying to run ggplot in RStudio

Tags: r, error-handling, version

I have encountered the following error on two separate occasions on my local machine, and when looking at answers online it seems like it has to do with packages when looking at other sources online. However, I wasn't able to find a solution that would work for me.

```
Error in make_ansi_style(x\[\["color"\]\]) :
Unknown style specification: br_magenta
```

It first happened when I called:

```
select(c(x, y, z, a, b, c), everything())
```

Then, it happened again when I called:

```
ggplot(data = distinct_sectors, aes(x = sector, y = percentage_of_loans, color = status)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

I have tried restarting R and also reinstalling all my packages and that didn't work. I assumed it would work since I thought it was just a versioning error.

Currently unsure what to do here.

Comment: It's difficult to help without knowing what x, y, etc. are. Could you edit your question to include these variables as they are saved in your R session?